# How to enter Text in overlay using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to enter text in a text field of overlay which is appearing after clicking on drop down option. But code is not getting focused to the overlay window and I am not able to input any text in the field.
Below is the HTML code of drop down option which will open new pop up:

```
<a href="#" objrid onclick="setTimeout(function() 
{YAHOO.action.flyers.tile87.hide();}, 0);openDialog('tile87_dialog', 
'tileId=null&lineId=0&columnName=ItemSheet&S_moduleContextId=cat', 'Ok', 
'Cancel', '', event);stopEventPropagation(event);; return false;" 
class="yuimenuitemlabel">
```

After clicking this, it will open overlay having below HTML code(refer image):

[HTML for ovarlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv1SZ.png)

Can anyone please suggest me how to solve this issue.

my code:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("New")).click();

driver.switchTo().activeElement();
By.className("yui-panel-container yui-dialog shadow focused");
By.className("yui-module yui-overlay yui-panel keyboardFocus");
By.className("bd");
WebElement enterText=driver.findElement(By.name("firstname"));
enterText.sendKeys("Hello");
```

NOTE: When I manually check this, focus is automatically setting on text field of overlay. But on doing same thing through code, is it not setting focus on text field.

Any tips on how to do this will be helpful.

Regards,

Krutika

Comment: it this overlay pop-up present inside a frame/

Comment: Can you add the code you have tried?

Comment: Yes, I have added it to my post.

Comment: That drop down option is inside frame. But this overlay is not inside frame.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask question you have to share full html-code. Otherwise to help you will be difficult.
I will try to do this, but I don't have full information for this.
As example, your code have to look like this:

```
//1. Initialization of driver
driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
//2. Get needed URL 
driver.get("http://someUrl");  
//3. Click this element will open alert  
driver.findElement(By.className("yuimenuitemlabel")).click();  
//4. Waiting for full rendering alert
try {  
    Thread.sleep(3000);  
} catch (InterruptedException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}  
//5. Enter needed text
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("the text you needed");
```

Comment: Yes, I tried using alert. But I got error massage as 'No alert found'.